# Issue with Text Input Direction in React Component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I'm building a Wysiwyg and I have a `content-editable` div in my component where users can input and format text. However, there's a problem with the text direction when I try to update the content.

Here's the code snippet:

```
const [htmlContent, setHtmlContent] = useState("");

[...]

<div
  contentEditable
  className="h-full w-full p-4 text-sm text-gray-600 focus:outline-none dark:text-gray-200"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlContent }}
  onInput={(e) => setHtmlContent(e.currentTarget.innerHTML)}}
/>
```

The issue is that when I update `e.currentTarget.innerHTML` using `setHtmlContent(e.currentTarget.innerHTML)`, the text appears to be reversed. However, if I log `e.currentTarget.innerHTML` inside the onInput event handler, the text is correct.

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-new?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A3%2C32&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4y8d1x0006356lz0ne4cfl%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4y8d1x0002356ls9fsypzy%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4y8d1x0003356lw7jch854%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4y8d1x0005356l38nqcc0g%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clq4y8d1x0002356ls9fsypzy%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4y8d1x0002356ls9fsypzy%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4y8x08007w356l01jph7ai%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A3%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A32%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A3%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A32%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq4y8x08007w356l01jph7ai%2522%257D%252C%2522clq4y8d1x0005356l38nqcc0g%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4y8d1x0004356l2xy0spy4%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4y8d1x0005356l38nqcc0g%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq4y8d1x0004356l2xy0spy4%2522%257D%252C%2522clq4y8d1x0003356lw7jch854%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4y8d1x0003356lw7jch854%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly used `onBlur` instead of `onInput` and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The cursor out of focus after setHtmlContent running,and then the cursor's position will be set to begin,so I add a useEffect function to move the cursor's position to end

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const div = document.querySelector('.h-full.w-full.p-4')
  div.focus()
  document.execCommand("selectAll", false, null);
  document.getSelection().collapseToEnd();
}, [htmlContent])
```